# Get Total Page Size Through PhantomJs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am using `phantomjs` (command line interface) to get HAR data and for this i am using `netsniff.js`, using like this command:

```
phantomjs netsniff.js YourURL > out.har
```

However this gives me the correct HAR data in the output file (`out.har`)
And using that HAR data i am calculating the page size, which i get from `"log > entries > response > bodySize"` which is present in the `"out.har"` and the total size which i get after calculation does not match the size which i get when i run the URL in the browser and in the network activity after doing inspect element at the bottom it shows (333kb transferred).

And also in the HAR data i am not getting `"Content-Length"` i think which gives the correct size if the file has status `(304 not modified also)` is it correct ??
If not how to get the correct page size ??.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't use netsniff.js, but I have some suggestion:

1. try disable cache by using `page.clearMemoryCache();`
2. phantomjs still have bug about `bodySize`, so I use both of them

```
> function getRealSize(response) {
>     var tmp, size;
>     for(var i=0; i<response.headers.length; i++) {
>         tmp = response.headers[i];
>         if(tmp.name == 'Content-Length') {
>             return parseInt(tmp.value, 10);
>         }
>     } 
> }
> size = getRealSize(response) || response.bodySize;
```

3. `Content-Length` can not be get in gzip, so disable gzip:

```
> page.customHeaders = {
>     'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip;q=0'
> };
```

(in fact, bodySize should never be used, but I didn't test all situation)

It works for me.

Comment: On your side is it showing the same numbers of page size as what we see when we do inspect element in browser, when all the files loads from the specified server not from cache.

Comment: On my side the size increases but still doesnt matches the number with the numbers what browser is showing.

Comment: I add step 3 to disable gzip to get correct size, it works for me.

Comment: Thanks so much. This helped me. I would take out the "|| response.bodySize" from the example code. You don't want to ever use response.bodySize.

Comment: I would like to add one missing piece here. If you are dealing with a site that is gzipped you could run in to issues and with phantomjs 2 you need: 

page.customHeaders = {
  "Accept-Encoding": "identity"
};

See here: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10930